# errors parsing int from text file c

Tags: c

Heres' my code so far, basically I am reading in a text file, and trying to save the each line by line input to a character array. The text file is read properly and saved to a character array which I then traverse through, and attempt to save the digits to an `int`.

*This isn't the entire code piece, as it's an assignment that I'm working on. The current code provided is simply for debugging purposes.

```
//takes input of file, saves it to array
char word[20];
scanf("%s", word);

//File to open
char line[10];
char number[10];

FILE *file;
file = fopen(word, "r");

if (file) {
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf("%s", line);
    int i,j=0;
    int parsedInt;

    for(i=2; i<sizeof(line) && !isspace(line[i]); i++) 
    {
      number[j] = line[i];
      j++;
    }
    sscanf(number, "%d", &parsedInt);
    printf("PARSED INT %d \n\n", parsedInt);
    parsedInt = 0;
```

Here's a sample input file, I have handled the `i` and `d`, which works fine.

```
i   10
i   12
d   10  
i   3
```

and heres sample output with those numbers

```
i   10
PARSED INT 10 

i   12
PARSED INT 12 

d   10
PARSED INT 10 

i   3
PARSED INT 32
```

Can someone explain why the last input gives a 32 instead of a 3 while the others are properly done?

Comment: `for(i=2; i<sizeof(line) ...` change to `for(i=2; i<strlen(line) ...` because not all of that array is in use.

Comment: `number` needs null-terminated.

Comment: what if you parsed only one character into line? `i=*2*; i<sizeof(line) && !isspace(line*[i]*); ` ? You'll read bad data.

Comment: try put `number[j] = 0;` after for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're not seeing everything, I'm going to take an educated guess that you're not clearing the number array before putting in values, so scanf() is going past your actual input.  Either put a '\0' after your for loop or use memset() or similar to clear the array before use.  So like:

```
memset(number, 0, sizeof(number));
for(i=2; i<sizeof(line) && !isspace(line[i]); i++) {
    number[j] = line[i];
    j++;
}
```

This assumes that '\0' == 0 (which is a damn safe assumption IME).